# How cone snail collection is done safely and legally?

Tags: poison, safety

I'm really intrigued by the hobby of cone snail collection. However, some cone snails are known to be venomous and dangerous to humans, so how are they freely available for purchase and traded online?

[image: nail]

Is it just the shell of a decomposed body of a dangerous species of cone snail eg. conus geographus that are sold as collector's items?

How are the specimens safely harvested? Is there regulations apart from endangered species laws governing their harvesting? Or is it an self governing risk based approach practice by those in the collector's trade?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about biology as defined in the [help].

Comment: Perhaps this question would be a better fit for The Great Outdoors SE?